# where to put options (warn =2) in my function in r

Tags: r

I have a function with 100 lines of for loop. My function return warning message `Warning message:
In f(init, x[[i]]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.

However, I do not know from where this warning comes? So I tried to trace back this message. So, I search for this problem, I found I can turn this warning to error using this:

by setting

```
options(warn = 2)
```

or this

```
options(error=utils::recover)
```

However, I do not really understand where I have to write these codes.
So, where should I write the `options(warn = 2)`, inside my function? 
any help please?

Comment: Woah there. Your function makes no sense. The variable `x` passed to the function isn't used within it and a whole lot of stuff not passed to the function is used instead.

Comment: my function works very well. I just want to know where to put the options. Also, could you please read my question, where I mentions the error

Comment: It's my understanding that `options()` is global so you can put it at the top of your script and have it run once.

Comment: `myfunc` is clearly accessing stuff in the global environment, not stuff passed to the function. So for anyone else trying to help without the data in your machine loaded, the function is gibberish

Comment: @MichaelBird I will try and see. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to know for which step inside the loop it fails? If so you could use `safely` from `purrr`. I tried writing something together, hope it helps. For my example though, everything fails, because I dont know what xvec and theta should be. Using safely, it will continue running even though hitting a error. You could also use print(i) inside the loop to see during which step it fails.

```
library(purrr)

output_list <- vector("list", 100)

myfunc <- safely(function(x){

  fn <- function(theta) { sum ( 0.5*(xvec - theta[1])^2/theta[2] + 0.5* log(theta[2]) ) }
  optim(theta <- c(0,5), fn, hessian=TRUE,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0,0),control = list(trace=1))

  out

})

for(i in 1:100){


  output_list[[i]] <- myfunc(rnorm(1))

}

errors <- lapply(output_list, function(x) !is.null(x$error)) %>% unlist
```

Comment: Try clearing your environment and then check if your example really works. Because theta and x is unclear.

Comment: it works! however, my question is just to show where I can but `options(warn =2)` that is all the idea of my question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. The function is just an example. the idea is just where I can put the options or how to trace back my warning in general.

Comment: you can put it wherever you want